# how to get rid of the white bar when using <div> tag

Tags: html, css

everytime I use div tag to make the header I end up getting a white bar at the top of the page , no matter what I do, it does not go

Things I tried

1.setting body margin padding outline to 0px

2.setting div tag margin padding outline to 0px

What Do I do please help.

ps:I'm just a beginner and I'm sorry if the question is too silly.

```
<body>
<div class="head">
<h1>webisteName</h1>
<form>
<label for="email">Email or Phone</label>
<input type="email" name="email">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
<p>Forgotten account?</p>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
outline:0px;
}
.head
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
outline:0px;
}
```

Comment: Would you please be able to post your html and css in the question? It will make it easier to see what the problem is

Comment: h1 has a default margin

Comment: I used overflow:auto; and it worked, I saw it from other question here, Sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

you could use margin with a (-) value or you could set the height to 102% or more. Might work but no guarantee.

```
Margin-top:-10px;
```

Comment: i added overflow:auto; to head and it worked, Thanks anyway :-)